# C# WPF Android like zoom if TextBox gets Focus

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, touch

I'm developing a `WPF` Application for Touch Devices. I want a behaviour like in `Android` Browser, if you focus a `TextBox` the screen 'zooms' in so you only see the `TextBox` and the virtual Keyboard.

I have already tried `Scaling` the `TextBox` and setting the Position if it has `Focus` but that doesn't work right. If somebody could point me in the right direction i would appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this function from this code

```
<TextBox Background="LightGreen" Width="100" Height="100" BorderBrush="Green">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.400" To="3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.300" To="125" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.300" To="125" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.150" To="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.150" To="100" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
        </TextBox>
```